# min-height 100vh creates vertical scrollbar even though content is smaller than viewport

Tags: html, css, flexbox, viewport-units

I'm applying `min-height: 100vh;` to a flexbox container and I get a vertical scrollbar when I use `justify-content: space-around;`

I don't want to force the height, but I don't understand why the scrollbar is there since the contents have smaller dimensions than the viewport.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/5.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <h1>min-height: 100vh;</h1>
    <h2>why is there a scrollbar here?</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    Be sure to expand window. 
    <a href="#">skill one</a>
    <a href="#">skill one</a>
    <a href="#">skill one</a>
    <a href="#">skill one</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using flexbox in this case? First apply browser reset CSS by adding `html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; } body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}` And for your .wrapper class, just add `.wrapper { height: 100%; }` So long as html and body each have 100% height, the wrapper class being a direct child will also be able to apply 100% screen height.

Comment: I also suggest you add `*,*:before,*:after { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box; }`

Comment: Do you have to use flex?

Comment: @Pegues: I am using flexbox because I want to vertically distribute my items (justify-content: space-around) . I've already set box-sizing to border-box, no change.
So : yes, I need to use flex.

Comment: It seems a bug in chrome...

Comment: `display: table` will also suite your purposes, although you may need to modify your markup a little in that case. This will then let you distribute vertically. And my suggestion of using box-sizing was if you didn't use flex. Sorry for lack of clarity in that comment.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman did I discover my first Chrome bug?:)

Comment: Try creating an extra container and giving that `100vh`. Then put your wrapper element inside that with height `100%`. It's the `justify-content` property that's creating extra white-space.

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos So you think that you can't be a lucky man? :)

Comment: @Jazcash can you provide a full answer pls? (btw I don't want to force height to be 100vh)

Comment: Change `min-height: 100vh` to `height: 100vh;`, and that gets rid of the whitspace: https://jsfiddle.net/rxz7jh9f/ It looiks like min-height: 100vh adds extra white space.

Comment: The point is to use `min-height: 100vh`

Comment: @Pegues : that's not an acceptable solution, I don't want to force the height as it might trim content off if the viewport isn't tall enough

Comment: The point may be to use min-height: 100vh, but if it adds extra whitespace, what else are you gonna do? Flex is widely misused to begin with.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uxgaaccr/ - Took a few more properties than I thought it would.

Comment: @Jazcash can you add an "answer" and add some reasoning behind it?

Comment: Switching `min-height: 100vh;` to `height: 100vh;` produces the same outcome as what @Jazcash provided, even with a reduced viewport and no trimming. Scrollbars appear in both solutions when the viewport height is too small. Perhaps you have additional markup not present here or a layout that is the reason for needing to use `min-height` instead of `height`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Adding flex-grow seems to do the trick:

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uxgaaccr/2/

Not sure why, but `height: 100%` on `.wrapper` doesn't seem to suffice, it needs `flex-grow` instead. I think there was some extra white-space coming from `justify-content: space-around` that was adding to the height. Not confident in my reasoning, but it seems to work...

Comment: and the plot thickens.. the workaround as such seems to work but we're still left wondering : why does this happen to begin with? I am having a peek at https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs as we speak. I can accept it now but I'd like to understand what's going wrong there

Comment: Updated my answer to use `body` instead, doesn't need that extra element. But yeah, weird bug.

Comment: accepting your answer even though it seems there's a simpler way.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @Jazcash's answer above, it can be simplified even more.

Essentially we need to move the `min-height: 100vh` to the parent element, and apply `display: flex` to it.
`flex-grow` isn't required.

https://jsfiddle.net/gkatsanos/uxgaaccr/3/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/5.0.0/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <h1>min-height: 100vh;</h1>
    <h2>why is there a scrollbar here?</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    Be sure to expand window. 
    <a href="#">skill one</a>
    <a href="#">skill one</a>
    <a href="#">skill one</a>
    <a href="#">skill one</a>
  </div>
</div>
```